# 'Enter Data' as list instead of list of lists in Azure ML Web Service

Tags: python, json, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

In Azure ML, I want to enter data to a model through a published Web Service. 
The way to tell this to the Web Service, as far as I can tell, it to have an 'Enter Data' box coming into the same input as the Web service.

[image]

You can then set you data format in the 'Enter Data' properties:

[image]

I want that list to be an arbitrary-length array of samples. This works if your input is:

```
{
  "Inputs": {
    "input1": {
      "ColumnNames": [
        "samples"
      ],
      "Values": [
        [
          1
        ],
        [
          2
        ],
        [
          3
        ],
        [
          4
        ],
        [
          5
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "GlobalParameters": {}
}
```

This is ok, but ideally it would be easier, and (more importantly) more network-efficient, if I could send them as:

```
{
  "Inputs": {
    "input1": {
      "ColumnNames": [
        "samples"
      ],
      "Values": [
        [
          1,2,3,4,5
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "GlobalParameters": {}
}
```

Is there a correct syntax to implement this?

Comment: If you are using python y don't you convert it in python itself ?

Comment: Convert what? I would prefer to use the latter syntax, but only the former syntax is recognised and accepted by the webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked internally to request a confirmation of your concern -

> 'Enter Data' as list instead of list of lists in Azure ML Web Service

but you expected feature is not available today in Azure ML Studio (The reason behind is Azure ML has to be able to read the input data as a tabular format, rows and columns). Such being the case, I would like to suggest you to submit a new feature request via below option:

On Azure ML Studio -> the upper right corner, there is a smiley face, please click that and send the feedback.

Should you have any further concerns, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks. Please keep us updated on when this feature is ready and I will change the accepted answer. For now the answer is this one -- i.e. NOT possible.

Comment: Thank you, gozzilli and we appreciate your feedback / new feature request that submitted via: On Azure ML Studio -> the upper right corner, there is a smiley face, please click that and send the feedback.

Comment: Yes, done that, thanks (sent some smiley and *many* frowny faces)